# Need to create select2 drop-down when click on text box

Tags: jquery-select2

i have a requirement that when i click on input type text box then select2 drop-down will automatically upon textbox and another text box will be automatically created down the select2 drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe below link useful for you [example](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomDropDownListStyling/index.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});
```

Also visit url for see all examples [select 2 examples](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Comment: Did not found solution of my question from above link. I need to create a drop-down when click on text box.